# How to display a larger image in a smaller ImageView with a sliding effect in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, imageview

i am having a image of size 1000X400px. Assuming the screen width of the target android device to be 320px. i want to slide that image from right to left. actually i want to do this for a sliding 2d scrolling platformer that i was trying to make. so please help as i am just a beginner(only 2 weeks into android dev.)

i was thinking if i could somehow make the program sleep for some time and i did this:

```
int START_X = 0;
int START_Y = 0;
final int WIDTH_PX = 320;
final int HEIGHT_PX = 400;

Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.background);
Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);

bg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
bg.setImageBitmap(img);

try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

img = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X+100, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);
bg.setImageBitmap(img);

try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

img = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X+200, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);
bg.setImageBitmap(img);
```

but it directly executes the last statements after waiting for 4000ms i.e.

```
img = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X+200, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);
bg.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the reason why you only see the effect of the last `setImageBitmap(img)` is because the method doesn't actually stop everything and draw the bitmap. It just sets the "drawing process" in a queue and it takes care of it a little bit later. 
The reason why it didn't render the bitmap even with the `Thread.sleep` call, is because you we're freezing the thread which renders the screen. :) The code you write (unless you write it in a separate thread) runs on the same thread as the code that handles the screen drawing. If you freeze that ... you basically block the entire app.

Second: As mentioned, `Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000)` is not a good approach to stop the thread. The main thread of an Android app is called the `UI thread`. If you freeze that, your ENTIRE app will freeze. So don't do it, whatever the case. :) Use [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead ... or the [postDelayed method of the Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247210/pausing-with-handler-and-postdelayed-in-android) or some other way. There are a couple more.

**Now, to get back to the matter at hand:**

- If you want to create an Android game, I suggest looking over the [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html) game development framework.
- But if you don't want to go right into that, the easiest way of doing what you've described above would be to use an `Animation`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141039/view-animation-right-to-left-android#answer-14399845) guy's answer.
- Another approach could be to use a `ValueAnimator`, see [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html) . What it does is ... you set a start and end value, i.e. screenWidth and 0 and you set a duration in miliseconds. Some "magic" happens in the back and a method `onAnimationUpdate` is called periodically with values between the start and end values you entered . You can take that value and set it as the `left` position of the `ImageView`. This might move the `View` from right to left and obtain the effect you want.

**A more "advanced" method of doing it**
Now ... a good way of doing it, which comes to mind, could be to:

- create a class that overrides the `ImageView` class.
- Set that in the .xml file of your layout and make it `match_parent`.
- In its constructor you could load the `Bitmap` value into memory and keep it in a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) local attribute.
- Now .. the next thing you could do is override the `onDraw` method of the `ImageView`.
- In it, you could use the `drawBitmap` method of the `Canvas` object. It accepts a `srcRect` and `destRect` which basically describesc what chunk from the original image goes where on the `ImageView's` canvas.
- You could have a separate thread to keep the duration by which the image moves along the screen and that thread could call the `invalidate` method of your `ImageView` thus forcing the `onDraw` method to be called and thus redrawing the bitmap a little bit more to the left.